# Opencv Static libraries linker error for ARM

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, static-libraries

Hi guys I have a problem with the static libraires linking. I am doing a c++ aplication in ubuntu 12.0.4 and I have to create an execute of this .cpp file for an ARM. This file contain opencv libraries.

So the first what I did was download the opencv source from the git repository:

git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git

Once that finish without problem, I create a new directory and I executed the Cmake:

cmake -DSOFTFP=ON  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=0 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../opencv/platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../opencv

Then I execute make, and start to build the static opencv libraries for ARM. Everything finish ok and I can see the static libraries just created.

So I try to compile like this:

arm-linux-g++ -static -o camera  IpCamPthread.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui

And then appear this error:

```
    /home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(rand.cpp.o): In function `cv::theRNG()':
    rand.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6theRNGEv+0xe): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
    rand.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6theRNGEv+0x18): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
    rand.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6theRNGEv+0x3e): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
    /home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(rand.cpp.o): In function       `cv::makeRNGKey()':    
    rand.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL10makeRNGKeyEv+0x14): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
    /home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function     `cv::Mutex::trylock()':
    system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5Mutex7trylockEv+0x4): undefined reference to     `pthread_spin_trylock'    
    /home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function     `cv::Mutex::unlock()':     
    system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5Mutex6unlockEv+0x4): undefined reference to   `pthread_spin_unlock'   
    /home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function    `cv::Mutex::lock()':    
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5Mutex4lockEv+0x4): undefined reference to `pthread_spin_lock'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::Mutex::operator=(cv::Mutex const&)':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5MutexaSERKS0_+0x34): undefined reference to `pthread_spin_destroy'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::Mutex::~Mutex()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5MutexD1Ev+0x28): undefined reference to `pthread_spin_destroy'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::Mutex::~Mutex()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5MutexD2Ev+0x28): undefined reference to `pthread_spin_destroy'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::Mutex::Mutex()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5MutexC1Ev+0xe): undefined reference to `pthread_spin_init'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::Mutex::Mutex()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv5MutexC2Ev+0xe): undefined reference to `pthread_spin_init'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::getTickCount()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv12getTickCountEv+0x8): undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::makeKey()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL7makeKeyEv+0x14): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::TLSDataContainer::getData() const':
system.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv16TLSDataContainer7getDataEv+0x20): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
system.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv16TLSDataContainer7getDataEv+0x26): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
system.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv16TLSDataContainer7getDataEv+0x156): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `icvGets(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL7icvGetsP13CvFileStoragePci+0x94): undefined reference to `gzgets'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `icvXMLSkipSpaces(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL16icvXMLSkipSpacesP13CvFileStoragePci+0x1b4): undefined reference to `gzeof'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `T.3388':
persistence.cpp:(.text.T.3388+0x11c): undefined reference to `gzeof'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `icvPuts(CvFileStorage*, char const*)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL7icvPutsP13CvFileStoragePKc+0x150): undefined reference to `gzputs'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `icvClose(CvFileStorage*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
persistence.cpp:(.text._ZL8icvCloseP13CvFileStoragePSs+0x136): undefined reference to `gzclose'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.a(persistence.cpp.o): In function `cvOpenFileStorage':
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0x7d0): undefined reference to `gzrewind'
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0x80c): undefined reference to `gzclose'
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0x88e): undefined reference to `gzopen'
persistence.cpp:(.text.cvOpenFileStorage+0xe3e): undefined reference to `gzclose'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngEncoder::writeDataToBuf(void*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder14writeDataToBufEPvPhj+0x28): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::readDataFromBuf(void*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder15readDataFromBufEPvPhj+0x14): undefined reference to `png_get_io_ptr'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder15readDataFromBufEPvPhj+0xec): undefined reference to `png_error'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::close()':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder5closeEv+0x2a): undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::readHeader()':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x1c): undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x26): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x2e): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x66): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xb2): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xe0): undefined reference to `png_read_info'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xfa): undefined reference to `png_get_IHDR'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x166): undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x180): undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x26): undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x68): undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x88): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xb2): undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x13c): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x148): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_strategy'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x18a): undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x19a): undefined reference to `png_write_info'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1aa): undefined reference to `png_set_packing'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1b4): undefined reference to `png_set_bgr'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x1c8): undefined reference to `png_set_swap'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x22e): undefined reference to `png_write_image'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x23e): undefined reference to `png_write_end'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x252): undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2e0): undefined reference to `png_init_io'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2f8): undefined reference to `png_set_filter'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x304): undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_png.cpp.o): In function `cv::PngDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x9e): undefined reference to `png_set_longjmp_fn'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xf8): undefined reference to `png_set_gray_to_rgb'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xfe): undefined reference to `png_set_interlace_handling'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x106): undefined reference to `png_read_update_info'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x128): undefined reference to `png_read_image'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x130): undefined reference to `png_read_end'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x14c): undefined reference to `png_set_rgb_to_gray'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x160): undefined reference to `png_set_bgr'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x168): undefined reference to `png_set_strip_alpha'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x174): undefined reference to `png_set_swap'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x180): undefined reference to `png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x188): undefined reference to `png_set_strip_16'
grfmt_png.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10PngDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x194): undefined reference to `png_set_palette_to_rgb'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `global constructors keyed to grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._GLOBAL__I_grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp+0x4): undefined reference to `jas_init'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer()':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv17JasperInitializerD1Ev[cv::JasperInitializer::~JasperInitializer()]+0x4): undefined reference to `jas_cleanup'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent16u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x1e): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xa4): undefined reference to `jas_image_writecmpt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder17writeComponent16uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xbe): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::writeComponent8u(void*, cv::Mat const&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0x1e): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xa4): undefined reference to `jas_image_writecmpt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder16writeComponent8uEPvRKNS_3MatE+0xbe): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x64): undefined reference to `jas_image_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x9e): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xd0): undefined reference to `jas_stream_fopen'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xde): undefined reference to `jas_image_strtofmt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xec): undefined reference to `jas_image_encode'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xf6): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::close()':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0xa): undefined reference to `jas_stream_close'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder5closeEv+0x18): undefined reference to 
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x94): undefined reference to `jas_image_getcmptbytype'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x118): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x172): undefined reference to `jas_matrix_create'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x18c): undefined reference to `jas_image_readcmpt'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1ae): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_createfromclrspc'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1be): undefined reference to `jas_image_chclrspc'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1ca): undefined reference to `jas_image_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1d4): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_destroy'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x246): undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_destroy'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp.o): In function `cv::Jpeg2KDecoder::readHeader()':
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x12): undefined reference to `jas_stream_fopen'
grfmt_jpeg2000.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv13Jpeg2KDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x22): undefined reference to `jas_image_decode'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function `cv::JpegEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x7c): undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x84): undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x158): undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x164): 
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function `T.441':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text.T.441+0x162): undefined reference to `jpeg_alloc_huff_table'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_jpeg.cpp.o): In function `cv::JpegDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x9a): undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x108): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x132): undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
grfmt_jpeg.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11JpegDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x17c): undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): In function `cv::ExrDecoder::readHeader()':
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xa): undefined reference to `Imf::globalThreadCount()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x20): undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::InputFile(char const*, int)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x2e): undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::header() const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x32): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::dataWindow() const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x5a): undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::header() const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x5e): undefined reference to `Imf::hasChromaticities(Imf::Header const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x68): undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::header() const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x6c): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels() const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x76): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x82): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x8e): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xf2): undefined reference to `Imf::InputFile::header() const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0xf6): undefined reference to `Imf::chromaticities(Imf::Header const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x144): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x15a): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder10readHeaderEv+0x166): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::findChannel(char const*) const'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): In function `cv::ExrEncoder::write(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x70): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::Header(int, int, float, Imath::Vec2<float> const&, float, Imf::LineOrder, Imf::Compression)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x96): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xaa): undefined reference to `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xb6): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xbc): undefined reference to `Imf::globalThreadCount()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0xd0): undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::OutputFile(char const*, Imf::Header const&, int)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x12e): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x13a): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x142): undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::setFrameBuffer(Imf::FrameBuffer const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x19c): undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::writePixels(int)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x21c): undefined reference to `half::convert(int)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x282): undefined reference to `half::convert(int)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2e6): undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::~OutputFile()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x2ec): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::~Header()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x324): undefined reference to `half::_eLut'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x378): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x384): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x3ae): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x3ba): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x3e4): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x3f0): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x40c): undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::writePixels(int)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x436): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x44a): undefined reference to `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x456): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x45c): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x470): undefined reference to `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x47c): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x482): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::channels()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x496): undefined reference to `Imf::Channel::Channel(Imf::PixelType, int, int, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x4a2): undefined reference to `Imf::ChannelList::insert(char const*, Imf::Channel const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x4d2): undefined reference to `Imf::OutputFile::~OutputFile()'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrEncoder5writeERKNS_3MatERKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE+0x4d8): undefined reference to `Imf::Header::~Header()'
/home/jesus/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(grfmt_exr.cpp.o): In function `cv::ExrDecoder::readData(cv::Mat&)':
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xec): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0xf8): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x14c): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x158): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1ae): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x1ba): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x244): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x250): undefined reference to `Imf::FrameBuffer::insert(char const*, Imf::Slice const&)'
grfmt_exr.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv10ExrDecoder8readDataERNS_3MatE+0x2a0): undefined reference to `Imf::Slice::Slice(Imf::PixelType, char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int, double, bool, bool)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was looking for something bu t I cannot get anything. 
Someone could help??
Thank you so much
Even I was investigate and I find that for to be sure that all of dependencies are included I should compile with the pkgconfig like this:

```
arm-linux-g++ -o example IpCamPthread.cpp `pkg-config --static --cflags --libs opencv`
```

and It creates an executable, but when I make "file" on the executable this is the result:
    example: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked  (uses      shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, not stripped
So is an ARM file but is dynamically linked then it does not work in my ARM, I do not undestand why make a dynamically linked when in my "opencv.pc" file there are this:

```
 # Package Information for pkg-config

 prefix=/home/jesus/opencv/build/install
 exec_prefix=${prefix}
 libdir=
 includedir_old=${prefix}/include/opencv
 includedir_new=${prefix}/include
```

> Name: OpenCV
>       Description: Open Source Computer Vision Library
>       Version: 2.4.9
>       Libs:  ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_contrib.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_stitching.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_nonfree.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_superres.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ocl.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ts.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_videostab.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_gpu.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_photo.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_objdetect.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_legacy.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_video.a ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_ml.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_features2d.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_highgui.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libIlmImf.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibjasper.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibtiff.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibpng.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibjpeg.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_flann.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/lib/libopencv_core.a
>   ${exec_prefix}/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libzlib.a -lrt -lpthread -lm
>   -ldl -lstdc++
>       Cflags: -I${includedir_old} -I${includedir_new}

All the libraries which use the open.pc are static, so I do not know why compile and build a dinamic executable.

Someone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic case of missing a few -lSomeLib statements to the linker.
pthread and gzip seem to be missing, among others. To manually find which libs you need, grep your "lib" folder for the symbol-name.

Comment: Hi idinev thank you for your answer, can I see some example of how use the grep in this case??Some one told me that maybe is libray format problem so, somenthing about that is not ARM format problem, there is some command which I can use for to know if some static library is ARM format??because with file I cannot do it. Thanksss

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys thanks Idinev I was looking for how add the libraries, and how to make sure that every libraries which I need are linked propertly.

So I try with pkgconfig How I said above, but I could not get the static executable and finally that was for a sintaxis error. I use this:

arm-linux-g++ -static -o example IPCamera.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

And it works, It created a executable, and when I execute "file executable" the output is:

example: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, not stripped

statically linked!